# Best practices for configuring IoC container in Asp .Net MVC Composition Root

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm building an ASP .Net MVC 2 application and I want to follow the ideas from Mark Seemann's book "Dependency Injection in .Net" so I registered my custom Controller Factory in the Global.asax file and I'm configuring the container within the Controller Factory like so:

```
public IController CreateController(RequestContext context, Type controllerType)  
{  
   var container = new Container();
   object controller;

   if(controllerType == typeof(MyControllerOne)
   {
      container.Configure(r => r.
         For<IService>().
         Use<ServiceOne>());
   }
   else if(controllerType == typeof(MyControllerTwo)
   {
       container.Configure(r => r.
          For<IService>().
          Use<ServiceTwo>());
   }
   ......

   return container.GetInstance(controllerType) as IController;
}
```

Now this code works (though it is possible I may have a mistake somewhere since I'm writing this by memory), the dependencies are being resolved and the correct controller is being instantiated with the correct dependency every time, but it seems that for every request the container is being configured to resolve the dependencies that will be needed at that moment. So my questions are:

- Isn't that redundant?
- Shouldn't the configuration of the container be done in the Global.asax as well so it is only done once? If so, how could this be done?
- By configuring the container the way I'm doing it, how will object lifetime be affected? I mean, eventually there will be repositories that should have a singleton lifetime, some others should be created once by HTTP request, and so for. What could be the implications?

Any comments, ideas and/or suggestions will be much appreciated.

By the way, the IoC container I'm using is StructureMap though I think that for this particular question it might not be too relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is, indeed, redundant to conditionally register each controller upon request. With StructureMap, the Controller Factory should look like this:

```
public class StructureMapControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IContainer container;

    public StructureMapControllerFactory(IContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }

        this.container = container;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(
        RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return (IController)this.container.GetInstance(controllerType);
    }
}
```

All services should be unconditionally registered in a single container instance. As an example, you can register all Controllers with StructureMap like this:

```
this.Scan(x =>
{
    x.AssemblyContainingType<HomeController>();
    x.AddAllTypesOf<IController>();
    x.Include(t => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t));
});
```

This is basically just following the [Register Resolve Release pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasePattern.aspx).

Comment: Seeman: Thank you so much Mark for both clearing this out and your book.

Comment: FWIW, the above code snippets are from the code download for the book.